# CollapsingToolbarLayout possible to define when to collapse?

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a working CollapsingToolbarLayout the only problem I am seeing is that the content being shown when expanded dissapears too quickly when scrolling down and was wondering if it possible to define at what point of the road the content should dissapear and the appbar appear. It seems like after collalsing ~25% it already hides the content and only shows the color of the appbar. In the Google Play App you can see that this happens really late when almost collapsing all.

Answer (score 1):

i would give you and example of how i achieved what you need.

Since you want the content to start dessapearing after for example 60%, first, declare a variable like this

```
private static final int PERCENTAGE_TO_SHOW_ELEMENT = 60;
```

Then you have to declare a variable to know if your element have been hidden already and a variable to track the scroll percentage

```
private int mMaxScrollSize;
private boolean mIsElementHidden;
```

After that, you have to add to your appBarLayout the listener called addOnOffsetChangedListener like this and override the method onOffsetChanged:

```
 yourAppBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
```

Inside the method onOffsetChanged, use this code:

```
@Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
            if (mMaxScrollSize == 0)
                mMaxScrollSize = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();

            int currentScrollPercentage = (Math.abs(verticalOffset)) * 100
                    / mMaxScrollSize;

            if (currentScrollPercentage >= PERCENTAGE_TO_SHOW_ELEMENT) {
                if (!mIsElementHidden) {
                    mIsElementHidden= true;
                    ViewCompat.animate(yourView).scaleY(0).scaleX(0).start();
                    ViewCompat.animate(anotherView).scaleY(0).scaleX(0).start();


                }
            }

            if (currentScrollPercentage < PERCENTAGE_TO_SHOW_ELEMENT) {
                if (mIsElementHidden) {
                    mIsElementHidden= false;
                    ViewCompat.animate(yourView).scaleY(1).scaleX(1).start();
                    ViewCompat.animate(anotherView).scaleY(1).scaleX(1).start();

                }
            }
        } else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            //You can change something if your layout is different in LANDSCAPE
        }

    }
```

You can play with the variable PERCENTAGE_TO_SHOW_ELEMENT to decide when to make your view(s) appear or dissapear.

Comment: Thanks, I was already using this listener for setting the title. What is yourView and anotherView?

Comment: And this solution does not override the hiding of the image I am showing, how is this supposed to work?

Comment: yourview and anotherView is the view you want to hide or display when the the scroll is happening and match with the % you want.

I use this code to hide and show and image, is working and is tested in a published app.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which implements **AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener** and override the **onOffsetChanged** method

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.imageview.placeholder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/quila2"
                android:tint="#11000000"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.9"
                />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.framelayout.title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.3"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main.linearlayout.title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="bottom|center"
                        android:text="@string/quila_name"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="@string/quila_tagline"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/main.framelayout.title"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:title=""
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >

            <Space
                android:layout_width="@dimen/image_final_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image_final_width"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main.textview.title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/quila_name2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Change the **PERCENTAGE_TO_SHOW_TITLE_AT_TOOLBAR** and **PERCENTAGE_TO_HIDE_TITLE_DETAILS** to get the desired effect.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

private static final float PERCENTAGE_TO_SHOW_TITLE_AT_TOOLBAR  = 0.9f;
private static final float PERCENTAGE_TO_HIDE_TITLE_DETAILS     = 0.3f;
private static final int ALPHA_ANIMATIONS_DURATION              = 200;

private boolean mIsTheTitleVisible          = false;
private boolean mIsTheTitleContainerVisible = true;

private LinearLayout mTitleContainer;
private TextView mTitle;
private AppBarLayout mAppBarLayout;
private Toolbar mToolbar;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bindActivity();
    mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);
    mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
    startAlphaAnimation(mTitle, 0, View.INVISIBLE);
}

private void bindActivity() {
    mToolbar        = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
    mTitle          = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    mTitleContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout_title);
    mAppBarLayout   = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
}

@Override
public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int offset) {
    int maxScroll = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
    float percentage = (float) Math.abs(offset) / (float) maxScroll;
    handleAlphaOnTitle(percentage);
    handleToolbarTitleVisibility(percentage);
}

private void handleAlphaOnTitle(float percentage) {
    if (percentage >= PERCENTAGE_TO_HIDE_TITLE_DETAILS) {
        if(mIsTheTitleContainerVisible) {
            startAlphaAnimation(mTitleContainer, ALPHA_ANIMATIONS_DURATION, View.INVISIBLE);
            mIsTheTitleContainerVisible = false;
        }
    } else {
        if (!mIsTheTitleContainerVisible) {
            startAlphaAnimation(mTitleContainer, ALPHA_ANIMATIONS_DURATION, View.VISIBLE);
            mIsTheTitleContainerVisible = true;
        }
    }
}

private void handleToolbarTitleVisibility(float percentage) {
    if (percentage >= PERCENTAGE_TO_SHOW_TITLE_AT_TOOLBAR) {
        if(!mIsTheTitleVisible) {
            startAlphaAnimation(mTitle, ALPHA_ANIMATIONS_DURATION, View.VISIBLE);
            mIsTheTitleVisible = true;
        }
    } else {
        if (mIsTheTitleVisible) {
            startAlphaAnimation(mTitle, ALPHA_ANIMATIONS_DURATION, View.INVISIBLE);
            mIsTheTitleVisible = false;
        }
    }
}

public static void startAlphaAnimation (View v, long duration, int visibility) {
    AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = (visibility == View.VISIBLE) ? new AlphaAnimation(0f, 1f) : new AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f);
    alphaAnimation.setDuration(duration);
    alphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    v.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, this solution does not seem to work. Also the layout does not combine with the code, it is missing some stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I didnt send the full layout

Comment: Here u go, attached the full layout, try this

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You don't obligatory need java code for this, you can define this with the style property **scrimVisibleHeightTrigger** but take in mind that the used value should be major than the size of the actionbar, sadly using ?acionBarSize did not work, so you must take into account the height of the appbar and add some DPs to it.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    style="@style/Widget.MyCustomWidget.CollapsingHeader"

<style name="Widget.MyCustomWidget.CollapsingHeader" parent="@style/Widget.Design.CollapsingToolbar">
    <item name="scrimAnimationDuration">200</item>
    <item name="scrimVisibleHeightTrigger">1dp</item>        
</style>
```